# get filename out of string

Tags: php

I do have the following strings of files.

```
/img/studio/record.JPG
/img/studio/view.JPG
/img/studio/doors.JPG
img/team/andy.jpg
img/team/jim.jpg
```

Now I would like to get only the filename to look in a db.

like: record.JPG

What the best way to get it?
(I need a php solution.)

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: see PHP [pathinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

Comment: Do you need While you storing or retrieving from database ?

Answer (score 4):

Use [basename](http://php.net/manual/de/function.basename.php):

```
echo basename('/img/studio/record.JPG');
```

will return `record.JPG`.

Answer (score 3):

try `pathinfo()`

```
pathinfo('/img/studio/record.JPG', PATHINFO_BASENAME)
```

Comment: @sectus it produces same results why not try

Comment: Try to write it... and you will see the difference.

Comment: whats faster: pathinfo('/img/studio/record.JPG', PATHINFO_BASENAME) or basename('/img/studio/record.JPG');

Comment: i think they are even.. they just differ on usage. basename() can only return your filename.. while in pathinfor you can add diff function on the second parameter depending on what you like to get on the string you input. - thats what i think it is :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `pathinfo` ([docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)):

```
$path = pathinfo('/img/studio/record.JPG');
echo $path['basename'];     // record.JPG
```

This way you can easily get directory name or file extension as well:

```
echo $path['dirname'];      // /img/studio
echo $path['extension'];    // JPG
```

Comment: whats faster:
pathinfo('/img/studio/record.JPG', PATHINFO_BASENAME)

or

basename('/img/studio/record.JPG');

Comment: `basename` is much simpler, so if there is any significant performance difference, I would bet on it. You can see their implementation: [pathinfo()](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/string.c#L1532) and [basename()](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/string.c#L1487).

Answer (score 1):

I though of provinding multiple ways to provide the same result:

```
$str = '/img/studio/record.JPG';

echo basename($str);
echo pathinfo($str, PATHINFO_BASENAME);
echo explode('/', $str)[count(explode('/', $str))-1];
echo strrev(explode("/", strrev($str))[0]);
echo preg_replace('/.*\//', '', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the [basename](http://php.net/basename) function should do what you need:

```
<?php 
echo basename("/img/studio/record.JPG");
?>
```

returns

```
record.JPG
```

Comment: You might want to include some information from this link, in case the link goes dead in the future.

Comment: @Dale In general an answer with just a link isn't a complete answer

Comment: @Bridge you're right! I'll edit it as soon as I can. Sorry, first answer ever. :P